# Lanzar tarea y más tarde reiniciarla Python, discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, asynctask

Tengo creado en python un monitor de twitter, lo quiero implementar con un bot de discord para que desde discord mediante comandos se le agregen usuarios a monitorear.

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

desde discord poner, .addUser(@diego) y que se meta en el bloc de notas del que extrae el monitor los usuarios ese nuevo introducido, para ello necesito parar la task del monitor y volver a iniciarla para que así se actualice el monitor y pille al nuevo usuario.
La cosa es que no se como hacer para cancelar la tarea y reiniciarla, también decir que el monitor usa varios hilos uno para cada usuario, la mision sería reiniciar el programa entero con todos sus hilos.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

async def monitoring():
    monitorTwitterHilos.main()
    

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): #Enciende el bot
        print('Logged in as')
        print(bot.user.name)
        print(bot.user.id)
        print('------')
        #taskMonitoring=bot.loop.create_task(monitoring()) #Para ejecutar tarea en segundo plano, mientras todo lo demas del bot se sigue ejecutando normal sin quedarse pillados en la funcion task
        #taskMonitoring.cancel
        #taskM=bot.loop.create_task(monitoring())
        #monitoring.start()
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(monitoring())
        print('------------ TASK LANZADA ------------')
    

@bot.command()
async def ping(message):
    await message.send("PONG")

@bot.command()
async def addUser(message, user):
    
   
    task1.cancel() #no funciona
    with open("usuarios.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(user)+"\n") 
        
    #monitoring.restart
    
    task1.start()  #no funciona
    
    await message.send("_Usuario: **"+ str(user)+"** añadido con exito_")



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias implemetar [task.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord.ext.tasks.loop) te adjunto un ejemplo

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=5.0)
async def status_task():
    await bot.change_presence(activity="JUGANDO"))
```